# Delphi Component Not Painted

Tags: delphi, panel, custom-component, tpanel

I have component (descendat of TPanel) where I implemented Transparency and BrushStyle (using TImage) properties.

All it's ok when I have one component of this type on the form. Bun when I pun on the form more components of this type only first visible component is painted. When form is moved and first component is under other window or outside desktop next component is painted.

```
unit TransparentPanel;

interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls, stdctrls;

type
  TTransparentPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    FTransparent: Boolean;
    FBrushStyle: TBrushStyle;
    FImage: TImage;

    procedure SetTransparent(const Value: Boolean);
    procedure SetBrushStyle(const Value: TBrushStyle);
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Transparent: Boolean read FTransparent write SetTransparent default
      True;
    property BrushStyle: TBrushStyle read FBrushStyle write SetBrushStyle default
      bsBDiagonal;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('TransparentPanel', [TTransparentPanel]);
end;

constructor TTransparentPanel.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FTransparent := True;
  FBrushStyle := bsBDiagonal;

  FImage := TImage.Create(Self);
  FImage.Align := alClient;
  FImage.Parent := Self;
  FImage.Transparent := FTransparent;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  if ((not (csDesigning in ComponentState)) and FTransparent) then
    Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
end;

destructor TTransparentPanel.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FImage) then
    FreeAndNil(FImage);

  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.Paint;
var
  XBitMap,
    BitmapBrush: TBitmap;
  XOldDC: HDC;
  XRect: TRect;
  ParentCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  {This panel will be transparent only in Run Time}
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) or (not FTransparent) or (FBrushStyle in [bsClear, bsSolid]) then
    inherited Paint
  else
  begin
    XRect := ClientRect;
    XOldDC := Canvas.Handle;
    XBitMap := TBitmap.Create;
    BitmapBrush := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      XBitMap.Height := Height;
      XBitMap.Width := Width;
      Canvas.Handle := XBitMap.Canvas.Handle;
      inherited Paint;
      RedrawWindow(Parent.Handle, @XRect, 0,
        RDW_ERASE or RDW_INVALIDATE or
        RDW_NOCHILDREN or RDW_UPDATENOW);

      BitmapBrush.Width := FImage.Width;
      BitmapBrush.Height := FImage.Height;

      BitmapBrush.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
      BitmapBrush.Canvas.Brush.Style := FBrushStyle;
      SetBkColor(BitmapBrush.Canvas.Handle, clWhite);
      BitmapBrush.Canvas.FillRect(BitmapBrush.Canvas.ClipRect);

      FImage.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, BitmapBrush);
    finally
      Canvas.Handle := XOldDC;
      Canvas.BrushCopy(XRect, XBitMap, XRect, Color);
      XBitMap.Free;
      BitmapBrush.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.SetBrushStyle(const Value: TBrushStyle);
begin
  if (FBrushStyle <> Value) then
  begin
    FBrushStyle := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end
end;

procedure TTransparentPanel.SetTransparent(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if (FTransparent <> Value) then
  begin
    FTransparent := Value;
    FImage.Transparent := Value;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;

end.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems, but it's hard to help you without knowing what the control should do. Could you please provide some more detail?

Answer (score 5):

OK, a few tips:

- Only one component is drawn, because during painting the client area of the control is invalidated again, so you create an infinite stream of *WM_PAINT* messages, and the second component never gets drawn. Until the first one is made invisible, as you describe. You can see this from the CPU load, having one of your components on a form uses 100% of one core on my system (Delphi 2007, component created at runtime).
- You should try to remove the bitmap you draw into, and make use of the DoubleBuffered property instead.
- What is FImage actually used for?
- If you modify the create parameters depending on the value of the Transparent property, then you need to recreate the window handle when the property changes.
- Maybe you can get rid of the component completely, and use a TPaintBox instead? It is transparent as long as you don't paint the background yourself. But I can't tell from your code what you actually want to achieve, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want a control that can contain other controls — like `TPanel` can do — and a control that can display the contents of the window underneath it — like `TImage` can do when its `Transparent` property is set. It appears you are under the mistaken impression that if you put one control on top of another, you'll get the behavior of both combined. *That's* what's wrong.

First thing you should do is get rid of the `TImage` control. That's just making things more complicated than they need to be. When you need to draw a brush pattern on the panel, draw it directly onto the panel.

Next, realize that the `ws_ex_Transparent` window style controls whether *siblings* of the window are painted first. That says nothing about whether the *parent* of the window gets repainted. If the parent of your panel has the `ws_ClipChildren` style set, then it will not paint itself underneath where your panel supposedly is. It looks like it would help you if the parent of your panel control had the `ws_ex_Composited` style set, but as a component writer, you don't get control over your controls' parents.

`TImage` is able to appear transparent because it is not a windowed control. It has no window handle, so the OS rules about painting and clipping don't apply to it. From Windows' point of view, `TImage` doesn't exist at all. What we in the Delphi world perceive as the `TImage` painting itself is really the parent window deferring to a separate subroutine to paint a certain region of the parent window. Because of that, the `TImage` painting code can simply not paint over some of the parent's area.

If I were doing this, I'd ask myself whether the control with the brush pattern really needed to be a container control. Could I instead just use an ordinary `TImage` with a repeating brush pattern drawn on it? Other controls can still go on top of it, but they won't be considered children of the pattern control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the [Graphics32 library](http://www.graphics32.org/wiki/) : it's very good at drawing things and works *great* with Bitmaps and Transparency

Answer (score 0):

If you want the panel to be transparent, all you need to do is override Paint and do nothing (or paint a transparent image, for example), and also catch the WM_ERASEBKGND message and do nothing here as well. This ensures the panel doesn't paint itself at all.

Make sure also to exclude the csOpaque flag from ControlStyle, so the parent knows it should paint itself underneath the panel.

The stuff you have in Paint is absolutely horrible, by the way (I mean the RedrawWindow thing). Get rid of it. And WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is meant for toplevel windows only, not for controls.